# Como abrir qualquer App no celular a partir de um link web

Tags: javascript, app, link, instagram-api

Queria saber se é possível abrir um link **direto no aplicativo**, e não no próprio **navegador** como é o que está acontecendo.
O link é para o Instagram:
Exemplo: `<a href='https://www.instagram.com/vansistem.info/'>...</a>`

Quando clicado queria que abrisse o **aplicativo** do Instagram no perfil do usuário.
Já vi que tem com fazer isso com o Facebook mais não sei como fazer com o ***Instagram***.
IMPORTANTE: quero fazer isso com ***HTML*** e/ou ***JavaScript***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que o apresentado aqui lhe auxilie.

Você poderá ver sobre isto diretamente neste link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249995/how-do-i-make-a-link-open-an-instagram-page-in-an-app-installed-on-android

Percorre diversas maneiras de solucionar este impasse.

Uma delas é:

```js
<a href="instagram://user?username=untitled.tiff">untitled.tiff</a>
```

Nesta situação, o app perguntará: "Deseja abrir no app?". Assim, abrirá no app.